# Math error during creation of countdown timer

Tags: vb.net, timer

I made a roughshod version of a countdown that has a resolution of 10ths of a second. I'm trying to express the result as `0:59`. However, during the time the counter is at 450 tenths of a second (or 45 seconds), I noticed that the math below is returning as `1:45`.

I switched the line of `intMinutesRemaining = intQuestionTimer / 600` to have a `\`, with fixes the error... but now when the clock is trying to read `1:00`, it will tick down to `0:60` then `0:59`. This subtraction is being controlled by a timer which has an interval of 100 milliseconds.

(`intQuestionTimer` will be equal to say 600 for a 60 second timer and then countdown from there with a `Timer` tick causing it to be deducted by 1.)

```
Private Sub UpdateQuestionTimer()
    'lblQuestionTimer.Text = intQuestionTimer.ToString
    Dim strFormat As String

    Dim intMinutesRemaining As Integer
    Dim intSecondsRemaining As Integer

    intMinutesRemaining = intQuestionTimer / 600
    intSecondsRemaining = intQuestionTimer Mod 600

    strFormat = "{0:0}:{1:00}"

    lblQuestionTimer.Text = String.Format(strFormat, intMinutesRemaining, intSecondsRemaining / 10)

End Sub
```

What change should I make to have this consistently display the correct formatted text?

Comment: What's the point in 10th of a second if you only display seconds?

Comment: @Amit: To ensure that an accurate stop/start is performed. Think of it this way, if I stop the timer with 9 seconds left on the dot, then start it up again, the timer will be at 8 seconds without having the full second ticking away. Another reason: Think of why the NBA and other sports organization now have 10ths of a second displayed when there is under 1 minute left on the game clock.

Comment: If intQuestionTimer is tenths of a second, then `intSecondsRemaining = intQuestionTimer Mod 600` is the number of tenths of a second into the current minute. You need to divide by 10 to get seconds.

Comment: OK, if it's a resumable timer, I guess it makes sense. Now regarding the question, are you certain about 450 showing 1:45?

Comment: @Blackwood: You might have missed the line `lblQuestionTimer.Text = String.Format(strFormat, intMinutesRemaining, intSecondsRemaining / 10)`

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I missed that in the `String.Format` statement.

Comment: @Amit: Correct. If I set the timer as 0:45, it will show up as 1:45. Maybe `Math.Floor` help out?

Comment: Even though Blackwood missed that part, it's not a good decision to name a variable with a misleading name, and there's no reason not to do the division at assignment time

Comment: @Amit: Valid point. I can make that change then.

Comment: Use a debugger, that doesn't sound right. 450 / 600 should be 0

Comment: 450 / 600 is 0.75. It's rounding up on the division. Using `Math.Floor` should resolve the issue on the `intMinutesRemaining = intQuestionTimer / 600` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the correct operator. You should use the \ operator also when showing the 10ths of seconds

```
Private Sub UpdateQuestionTimer()
    'lblQuestionTimer.Text = intQuestionTimer.ToString
    Dim strFormat As String

    Dim intMinutesRemaining As Integer
    Dim intSecondsRemaining As Integer

    intMinutesRemaining = intQuestionTimer \ 600
    intSecondsRemaining = intQuestionTimer Mod 600

    strFormat = "{0:0}:{1:00}"

    lblQuestionTimer.Text = String.Format(strFormat, 
    intMinutesRemaining, intSecondsRemaining \ 10)

End Sub
```

The operator / is used for floating point operations, but when your `intQuestionTimer` value is 599 dividing it by 10 produces 59,9. That value is rounded up to 60 again. Instead using the \ operator for integer operation the previous division yields 59 without the decimal part and it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a rounding issue. Both variables are defined as integers. However, you're using the `/` floating point division operator, so that the result of the operation is rounded up and stored in the integer variable.

Use the integer division operator `\`, instead, or `Math.Floor`.